# Only getting string while iterating through json data

Tags: python, json, api

JSON:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "9": {
            "1695056": {
                "id": "1695056",
                [...]
                },
                "csevents": {
                    "2807": {
                        "id": "2807",
                        "startdate": "2019-01-24 18:45:00",
                        "service_texts": [],
                        "eventTemplate": "1"
                    },
                    "2810": {
                        "id": "2810",
                        "startdate": "2019-01-31 18:45:00",
                        "service_texts": [],
                        "eventTemplate": "1"
                    }
                 }
            },
            "1695309": {
                "id": "1695309",
                [...]
                },
                "csevents": {
                    "3601": {
                        "id": "3601",
                        "startdate": "2019-05-17 18:45:00",
                        "service_texts": [],
                        "eventTemplate": "1"
                    }
```

I try to get the members from "csevents" ("2807", "2810", 3601") with python. Problem is that i don't know the IDs in "9" ("1695056", "1695309") while coding.

So i tried to iterate through "9" and then through "csevents" but if i iterate through "9" i only get a string so i can't iterate through "csevents" anymore.

Python:

```
for whatever in json_object['data']['9']:
    for id in whatever['csevents']:
        print(id)
```

So that doesn't work. Does anybody know how I can solve that?

Thanks

Comment: You should post (relevant parts of) the json contents verbatim, and also the output of the script (and also `print(whatever)` before the inner loop).

Comment: What about `rand_dict = whatever['csevents'][id]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to clean up your JSON string to get it to work, but looking at your solution is seems like you're iterating directly from your `dict`, what you should be using is `.items()` or `.values()`:

```
for key, value in json_object['data']['9'].items():
    # We can use .keys() here since we only need the IDs from csevents
    csevent_keys = list(value['csevents'].keys())
    print(csevent_keys)

# Output
['2807', '2810']
['3601']
```